# Why does Careers ask me to sign in if I'm already signed in?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, cv

When I go to my Public CV, even when I'm currently signed into SO/C.SO, the blue bubble in the upper-right corner is asking me to **sign in** or **join now**. I know I don't need to do either but it's just sort of confusing/annoying.

Can we get the system to do a "is logged-in" check to determine whether those portions of the blue-bubble should be visible or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, you're referring to the public CV preview. We can probably mask that part for logged in users, but that is how 99.99% of the world will see your CV page, so it is accurate.. for the record. :)

Comment: @Jeff: That would be a nice & simple tweak Jeff, thanks man.

Comment: maybe you could just make it an image, not an actual link?  like you say, it lets you see precisely what it will look like to 99.99% of the world...